# How to forward some touches to the next view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

The app in question differentiates between Apple Pencil inputs and finger touches, and have two full-screen views to handle the stylus and the finger touches separately. The stylus handling view is a transparent `UIView` laid on top with no subviews (all drawing performed using OpenGL ES); while the finger responding view is a `UITableView` with a big subview hierarchy. Currently the stylus handling works. However the finger touches are not passed to the correct view (and ended up traversing the responder chain up to the view controller directly instead.)

How to make one view responds to only Apple Pencil events, and pass all remaining events to the other view in the layout?

To keep in mind, [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719412/how-to-ignore-touch-events-and-pass-them-to-another-subviews-uicontrol-objects) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133248/how-to-differentiate-whether-a-user-is-tapping-the-screen-with-his-finger-or-an) does not solve my specific question, as the two views have the same hit area, but responds to different **type** of touches. The view on top need to pass the finger events down to the view on bottom.

Comment: Seems like you need to distinguish between Apple Pen touch vs. finger touch. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133248/how-to-differentiate-whether-a-user-is-tapping-the-screen-with-his-finger-or-an

Comment: @DatNguyen That question did **not** solve my problem, as it involves passing some of the touches down to another view instead of handling natively.

Comment: How do I bump the question?

Comment: I don't think you can bump your question to make it appears in the first page. If you have done more development/debugging and still having issues, you can consider asking a new question that is more specific to your current problem. It seems like no one can answer this question as is.