# Distinguish between finger touch and Apple Pencil touch

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitouch, apple-pencil

I'm using SceneKit to render a 3D model on an iPad Pro. My requirement is that I'd like to perform different interactions when using the Apple Pencil.

Is there a way to distinguish between a finger touch and an Apple Pencil touch?

I tried overriding the `touchesBegan` function and filtering the `UITouch` in the `Set` to ignore the ones with type `pencil`, but that doesn't seem to do anything...

EDIT: I'm more interested in handling these 2 different types of touches (i.e. when the there's a finger touch event, I want to do some action A. If it's pencil, I want to do action B). Which methods do I even override to achieve this segregation?

Comment: Look at the majorRadius of the UITouch object. Use that for filtering. The pencil has a unique value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to differentiate whether a user is tapping the screen with his finger or an apple pencil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133248/how-to-differentiate-whether-a-user-is-tapping-the-screen-with-his-finger-or-an)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way of checking is a UITouch object will have additional information that comes from a stylus (Such as Apple Pencil). Check if this information exists on the object and if it does the UITouch object came from a stylus.

For more in-depth information I have linked below an input guide for the Apple Pencil from the developer documentation.

Can you provide code however as the type on UITouch should still be reported correctly?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pencil_interactions/handling_input_from_apple_pencil

Comment: Hi, I guess I should have worded my question a little better. Do you know how to perform some handler if the touch is from the pencil and some other different handler if it's finger touch?

Answer (score 0):

The key is the UIGestureRecognizer class. "The base class for concrete gesture recognizers" said apple documentation

It has a property called  [allowedTouchTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624223-allowedtouchtypes) that can be used to distinguish different type of touches.

> This property is an array of touch types that recognizes whether the touch is direct or indirect. For a list of all possible touch types, see UITouch.TouchType enumeration in UITouch. The default value of this property contains all touch types.
>
> The gesture recognizer distinguishes between the touch types by setting the allowedTouchTypes property to UITouch.TouchType.pencil when tracking Apple Pencil touches, and to UITouch.TouchType.direct when tracking touches from a finger.

Also, [i've Found this one on the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/leveraging_touch_input_for_drawing_apps). 
this tutorial provides helper method that can help Distinguish Between Finger and Apple Pencil Touches.
=>

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pencil_interactions/handling_input_from_apple_pencil) says, "A touch object originating from Apple Pencil contains additional information, including the azimuth and altitude of Apple Pencil and the amount of force recorded at its tip." However, checking `(touch.altitudeAngle > 0)` didn't work for me because some finger touches also have an angle set. I tried `(touch.majorRadiusTolerance == 0)` and that seemed reliable. Then I realized we can simply check `(touch.type == .pencil)`.